# Referencing the DisplayNameFor in a child View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model:

```
 public class ObjectiveVM
 {
    public DateTime DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public IList<ObList> obList { get; set; }
    public class ObList
    {
        public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public int AnalystId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AnalystName { get; set; }
        public bool Include { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

The view model is populated in the controller, and has the information I need:
[image: ss]

How, in my view, do I access the DisplayName for the table headers:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM>
    ...
    ...
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ObList.Include)
    </th>
```

when trying above, I get the error:

`'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead`

I also tried:

```
@model Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM
```

...but again received the error:

```
 'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ObList` (with capital O) is a nested class. `DisplayNameFor` however expects some member of existing instance of a type to operate with. Member that you are probably trying to address is `obList`, so here is how to call its `Include` property:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.obList[0].Include)
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei - that still gives the error:  'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead - thank you.

Comment: @fixit, make sure you did not capitalize "o" in `obList`

Comment: You are correct - my mistake, thank you for your help.  I'll mark as the answer in a minute or so, when SO allows.  Cheers @Andrei !

Comment: That's not gonna work if the model is empty or obList has no items

Comment: @MaksimVi., agreed. Empty model (you mean `model == null`, right?) should be checked separately. But I cannot think at the moment about a good way to handle obList with no items. Any suggestions?